# PHP MPDF53, background image

Tags: php, mpdf

This code creates a pdf from html. Here is an [example](https://eurozaem.ru/static/test.pdf). How to make the background image on the second page like on the first page?

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8','A4','8','',10,10,22,22,10,20);
$html = '<div id="for_pdf">
    <h3>some text</h3>
    ...
    <h3>some text</h3>
</div>';
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('./static/css/print.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output("$doc_name.pdf",'D');
```

Part of print.css file:

```
#for_pdf{
    background-image: url("/static/image/pdf_img/big_logo.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but the solution is to use the @page selector in CSS.

```
@page {
    background: url("/static/image/pdf_img/big_logo.gif") 50% 0 no-repeat;
}
```

*I turned your CSS into shorthand but does the same thing.

The above code should be added to your css file or inside  tags in your html file.

@page should also be the first call in the css otherwise mPDF will ignore it.

Using @page will make changes to every page no matter how many you have. You can also do some more cool stuff by doing "@page :first {}" which allows you to put custom settings for just the first page and then use regular @page to affect the rest differently from the first.